# inline style css only works

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

i'm tring to make something looks good

i was tring to use css but i got a problem

only a inline style is working...

```
reply new {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 5vh;
    }
    reply new writer {
        width: 20px;
    }
    reply new content {
        width: 20px;
    }
```

- 

```
<input type="text" class="reply new writer form-control input-sm" style="width: 20px">
<input type="text" class="reply new content form-control input-sm">
```

it doesn't work.

but

```
<input type="text" class="reply new writer form-control input-sm" style="width: 20px">
<input type="text" class="reply new content form-control input-sm">
```

it works.

what should i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> reply new
> ```

This is a [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors), followed by a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), followed by another type selector. It will match:

```
<reply><new></new></reply>
```

… which is not valid HTML.

---

To select an element based on a class you need to use a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), which starts with a `.`.

To select an element based on multiple features, you need to combine them directly without putting descendant combinators between them.

```
.reply.new {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry. I knew that, but i missed that. It's too hard to find a small tiny typing errors....

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a "." before you're class selectors.

When trying to target a "class" you need to use `.ClassName`
[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) has examples and a good interactive example too.

Also if you want to target two classes it's:

```css
.ClassOne.ClassTwo
```

That will target:

```html
<div class="ClassOne ClassTwo">Hello</div>
```

Comment: oh... i got a big mistake